# Show unique color for unique value

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a 2d numpy array obtained by reading from an image. The unique values of the array are 0, 1, and 2. I want to plot the image showing unique colors red, green, and blue for the values 0,1, and 2 respectively.

```
plt.imshow(data, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(['red'])
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.colors import from_levels_and_colors
cmap, norm = from_levels_and_colors([0,1,2,3],['red','green','blue'])
plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

Comment: It needs n+1 values for n colors, for eg 0 to 1 will be assigned red and 2 to 3 will be assigned blue,they are bounding intervals