# Plot multiple images with identical color assignments using matplotlib's imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, imshow

I have multiple images (numpy arrays) whose data values correspond to N different classes.  Each image does not necessarily contain examples of each class.  For example, there might be a total of 12 different classes (0:11), however, one image might only contain classes 1:9.

I would like to plot each image such that the color assigned to each class is the same across all images.

I've looked into several answers:  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719304/python-imshow-set-certain-value-to-defined-color) the accepted and popular answers didn't work across multiple images.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248042/show-unique-color-for-unique-value) seems like it could work but I would really like to use a color map (`from matplotlib import cm`) so as not to manually set colors. I would also like a means to create an appropriate colorbar containing all classes.

The code I've tried is below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
t2 = t1.copy()
t2[1,1] = 10
t3 = t2.copy()
t3[1,1] = 11

cmap = cm.get_cmap('tab20', 11)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)

axs[0].imshow(t1, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 11)
axs[1].imshow(t2, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 11)
axs[2].imshow(t3, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 11)
```

Comment: `cm.get_cmap('tab20', 11)` only contains 11 different colors, while you need 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, in case you want to define your own colors and not a predefined `cmap`, I created the following code specifically for this some time ago.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

C_p = 11 # Classes

colour_names = [ # Your predefined colours
    "blue",
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "orange",
    "black",
    "purple",
    "green",
    "turquoise",
    "grey",
    "maroon",
    "silver",
    "white"
]

colour_dict = { # Color mapping (class -> colour)
    i: mpl.colors.to_rgb(colour_names[i])
    for i in range(C_p + 1)
}

# Create a colormap (optional)
colours_rgb = [colour_dict[i] for i in range(C_p)]
colours = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colours_rgb)

norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(C_p + 1) - 0.5, C_p)

plt.figure() # If you only want to plot one
plt.imshow(t2, cmap=colours, norm=norm)
cb = plt.colorbar(ticks=np.arange(C_p))
plt.axis("off")
```

Example with your `t1`, `t2` and `t3`:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)
axs[0].imshow(t1, cmap = colours, norm=norm)
axs[0].set_title("t1")
axs[0].axis('off')
axs[1].imshow(t2, cmap = colours, norm=norm)
axs[1].set_title("t2")
axs[1].axis('off')
im = axs[2].imshow(t3, cmap = colours, norm=norm)
axs[2].set_title("t3")
axs[2].axis('off')
p0 = axs[0].get_position().get_points().flatten()
p1 = axs[1].get_position().get_points().flatten()
p2 = axs[2].get_position().get_points().flatten()
ax_cbar = fig.add_axes([p0[0], 0.08, p2[0], 0.05])
plt.colorbar(im, cax=ax_cbar, ticks=np.arange(C_p), orientation='horizontal')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: example run]

Comment: Note that simply `mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colour_names)` would also work.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that. I thought it needed rgb values. Thanks

Comment: This is the more complete solution given it has a means to create a colorbar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `cm.get_cmap` needs to be adjusted to handle all the possible categories/classes in the images.  The below code works:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
t2 = t1.copy()
t2[1,1] = 10
t3 = t2.copy()
t3[1,1] = 11

cmap = cm.get_cmap('tab20', 12)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)

axs[0].imshow(t1, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 11)
axs[1].imshow(t2, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 11)
axs[2].imshow(t3, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 11)
```